# Compile NextJS Application after build to an executable

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel, next.js13, nexe

I want to turn a built next js application into an executable using nexe or pkg.

After building my next js application the .next folder contains
[NextJS .next folder after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCmQW.png)

I want to use the pkg or nexe node packages to turn my application into an executable, the user will run it, a terminal will display that a server is listening on port 3000 finally the user opens the browser and he is able to use the app.
I'm struggling to integrate these packages to attain my goal.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are some notes here: https://medium.com/@evenchange4/deploy-a-commercial-next-js-application-with-pkg-and-docker-5c73d4af2ee
Im trying also to archive the same goal but no results. 
did you have some updates?